# How to change text font color, while hovering over any part of a <td> or <tr>?

Tags: html, css

I have a table without background, I want the `<td>` or even the entire `<tr>` to change background color and font color on Hover.
I know how to change the background color and the text color on Hover

```
 tr:hover {
       background-color: #ddd;
       color: black;
}
```

However, that will only change the Text color if I hover over the actual text, and I want to change both the text and background colors if I hover over any part of the `<td>`/ `<tr>` not necessarily over the Text itself.

Comment: Could you kindly verify that your code includes that pound (`#`) before the `black` keyword? If so, that's a syntax error and text color will not change. Additionally, could we see a bit more HTML/CSS? If you have color styles applied to your `td`, the `tr:hover` styles won't inherit.

Comment: The code you pasted looks ok, so something else must be wrong. Please honor the previous request and post a [reprex], thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this in web it may help you:

```html
<style style="text/css">
  .hoverTable{
    width:100%; 
    border-collapse: collapse; 
  }
  .hoverTable td{ 
    padding: 7px; 
    border: #444fa6 1px solid;
  }
  /* Define the default color for all the table rows */
  .hoverTable tr{
    background-color: #6b76d1;
  }
  /* Define the hover highlight color for the table row */
  .hoverTable tr:hover {
    background-color: #9aa3ed;
    color: #a456ba;
  }
</style>

<table class="hoverTable">
  <tr>
    <td>Text 1A</td>
    <td>Text 1B</td>
    <td>Text 1C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Text 2A</td>
    <td>Text 2B</td>
    <td>Text 2C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Text 3A</td>
    <td>Text 3B</td>
    <td>Text 3C</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @EdwinRamirez45 No problem :D